# Bar button item does not show up from UISplitViewController delegate's splitViewController:willHideViewController:

Tags: ipad, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

So, I've got a split view controller, with the master controller set up as the delegate. When rotating into portrait view, I'd like to add a button to show the popover to the navigation bar. My `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:` delegate method is successfully called, and the bar button item is non-nil, but when I set it as the `leftBarButtonItem` or `rightBarButtonItem` on the navigation item, nothing happens. The navigation item is the right one, as setting a `titleView` or adding other bar button items works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out that the bar button item supplied to the delegate method might not have a title. And if it doesn't have a title, it's not displayed as an empty button, but not at all. So the fix for this is:

```
barButtonItem.title = @"MyButtonTitle";
```

Before adding it as a `leftBarButtonItem` or `rightBarButtonItem`, upon which it shows up and works as expected.